# Trying to get Morefunc Indirect.exe to update automatically with Excel 2016 (32 bit)

Tags: microsoft-excel

Have used Morefunc Indirect.exe for some time and know the problems with Windows 10, 32 bit & 64 bit. I am now using office 365 with Excel 2016 (32 bit) and Indirect.exe does work BUT will not update the values automatically i.e. I need to go into each cell and 'double-click' & enter for it to update. Any info on how to get it working?

Comment: Being an add-in with small user community the best option could be to contact its developer,  have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks, but not an option with Morefunc Add-In.